# How to determine which parameter caused the HttpMessageNotReadableException during bean validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation

For the Page Number if someone has entered "test" , I want to customise the error message `"Please provide the correct type for the parameter : pageNo"`.

**Request Object:**

```
 {
        "pageSize":6,
        "pageNo":"test",
        "sortBy": "lastModifiedTime"
    }
```

How do i determine the the parameter which caused the exception :

```
@ExceptionHandler({ HttpMessageNotReadableException.class, HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class,
            HttpMessageNotWritableException.class,
            ConversionNotSupportedException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> handleRequestErrors(final Exception ex) {
        RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
        response.setCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        response.setStatus(false);
        response.setMsg(ex.getMessage());
        if (ex instanceof HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException 
                || ex instanceof HttpMessageNotWritableException
                || ex instanceof HttpMessageNotReadableException) {
            response.setMsgCode(AppCode.E_GEN_CONTENT_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

The same scenario can be handled for the query param validation :

**Controller Advice :**

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> handleMethodArgumentTypeMismatchException(HttpServletRequest request,
            MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException exception) {
        RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
        response.setCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()); // 400
        response.setStatus(false);
        response.setMsgCode(AppStrings.BAD_REQUEST);
        String param = exception.getName();
        response.setMsg("Please provide the correct type for the parameter : " + param);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

**Controller Class :**

```
    public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> getNotifications(
                @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") @Min(0) IntegerpageNo,
@RequestParam(defaultValue = "5") @Min(1) Integer pageSize,
@RequestParam(defaultValue = "lastModifiedTime") String sortBy) {
```

Comment: Should this value not be tested at the endpoint? You can throw custom error message there.

Comment: What do `getRootCause` and `getMostSpecificCause` say on those exceptions? It's possible that there are nested exceptions with info you want.